# I have group of object and i want to make it mirror effect

Tags: mirror

I have a group of object and i want to mirror that object how is possible and to make a group of object mirror effect

Comment: do not ask the same question again. if you need more clarification edit your first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the entire Group by -1 in your Mirror-direction. Use the 3D Curser as Pivot Point, place the 3D curser as your Mirror.